# Recorrer un array generado a partir de varias consultas

Tags: php

Tengo este problema:

```
// la tabla se llama gradoSeccionDocente
$idGradoseccionesDocentes = $_POST["asignaciones"]; //Matriz id de los grados

$objetoSeccion = new Seccion(); // instancia del objeto

foreach ($idGradoseccionesDocentes as $filas) { // bucle que recorrera cada 
    idGradoseccionDocente 

    $objetoSeccion->setterId($filas); // segun los ids que vengan en el array

    $consulta = $objetoSeccion->getSeccionWithId();
```

//  consultara el numero de veces segun ids se encuentren en el array "$filas"

```
    $row = $objetoSeccion->convertirEnArray($consulta); 
    // aca necesito consultar el array de manera que pueda acceder a todo los id 
    // de mi tabla que estan relacionados EJEMPLO: idGrado,idDocente,idSeccion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> // la tabla se llama gradoSeccionDocente
>   $idGradoseccionesDocentes = $_POST["asignaciones"]; //Matriz id de los grados

```
$objetoSeccion = new Seccion(); // instancia del objeto

foreach ($idGradoseccionesDocentes as $filas) { // bucle que recorrera cada 
    idGradoseccionDocente 

    $objetoSeccion->setterId($filas); // segun los ids que vengan en el array

    $consulta = $objetoSeccion->getSeccionWithId(); //  consultara

    $row = $objetoSeccion->convertirEnArray($consulta); 
    // aca necesito consultar el array de manera que pueda acceder a todo los id 
    // de mi tabla que estan relacionados EJEMPLO: idGrado,idDocente,idSeccion

    //pues aca lo que tienes que realizar una consultar en join relacionados partiendo de tu tabla raiz que seria "gradoSeccionDocente" ejemplo 
    //SELECT * FROM gradoSeccionDocente AS gSD 

    "Aqui pues consultas el dato relacional del grado y se hace un join o union de los datos consultados de gradoSeccionDocente y Seccion relacionados por el idSeccion"
    //INNER JOIN Seccion AS Secc ON Secc.id = gSD.idGrado 

    "Aqui pues consultas el dato relacional del grado y se hace un join o union de los datos consultados de gradoSeccionDocente y Seccion relacionados por el idDocente "
    //INNER JOIN Docente AS Doc ON Doc.id = gSD.idDocente 


    //La consulta quedaria algo asi al final

    SELECT * FROM gradoSeccionDocente AS gSD 
        INNER JOIN Seccion AS Secc 
            ON Secc.id = gSD.idGrado 
        INNER JOIN Docente AS Doc 
            ON Doc.id = gSD.idDocente 

    //pero al consultar los id se van a sobremontar asi que hay que separarlos en el select y resultaria esto

    SELECT gSD.*, Secc.id AS Secc.idSecc, Doc.id AS idDoc FROM gradoSeccionDocente AS gSD 
        INNER JOIN Seccion AS Secc 
            ON Secc.id = gSD.idGrado 
        INNER JOIN Docente AS Doc 
            ON Doc.id = gSD.idDocente 
    WHERE gSD.id = idGradoseccionDocente 

    //Este seria el resultado final de su consultar para las multiples relaciones de datos y solo los llamas     
}
```

Comment: Bueno la cosa es que esta bien como le haces...peroo aca mi problema es que al controlador desde la vista llegan ids de la tabla idGradoSeccionDocente eentonces como veras hice un foreach por cada id que llegue y dentro del for each se consultara por cada id y de ahi se traera la data de todos los docentes por id

Comment: Siento la tardanza..estaba con esto del fin de año..prosigo eeentonces necesito una forma de..separar la data de los docentes y usarla para los metodos setter y asi no romper la arquitectura mvc. De no poder resolverlo lo hare sin MVC y despues pensare como